# Output Print is Slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I am writing a script, this part of the code is making my script output to print slow. I think its the nested loop which is causing the issue ( Used Dictionary concept there ). Is there any alternative way I can make my script to print the result without waiting for it.

```
Log = open("file.txt")
for LogLine in Log:
    flag = True
    for key, ConfLine in Conf.items():
        for patterns in ConfLine:
            patterns = DateString + patterns
            if re.match(patterns, LogLine):
                flag = False
                break 
        if(flag == False):
            break 
    if(flag):
        print LogLine.strip()
```

Comment: what is `Conf` you are referring to in  `Conf.items()` ?

Comment: its defining dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C Panda's answer is good but it's not obvious that a regex full of `|` is the fastest way to try all regexes. Test the performance of this alternative:

```
pats = [re.compile(date_string+pat) for conf in Conf.values() for pat in conf]

with open('file.txt') as log:
    for line in log:
        if any(pat.match(line) for pat in pats):
            print(line.strip())
```

On a side note, here's how your current code could be written with a clean `break` and no need for `flag`:

```
for ConfLine, patterns in ((c, p) for c in Conf.values() for p in c):
    patterns = DateString + patterns
    if re.match(patterns, LogLine):
        break
else:
    print LogLine.strip()
```

Comment: I would like to think that your first one and mine are practically equivalent. I am alternating and submitting to the regex engine and here python is evaluating the `or`. I learned that from *Bealey*. :)

Comment: @CPanda indeed, they are equivalent. I was trying to express that in the beginning. One might be faster, I don't know which. You certainly did the important part of the optimisation. Also OP has now learned about `any` which is valuable.

Comment: Roger. I was heading for being terse.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It will give you a lot of speed up. Apply appropriate changes for Python 2.x

```
pats = (date_string+pat for conf in Conf.values() for pat in conf)
master_pat = re.compile('|'.join(pats))

with open('file.txt') as log:
    for line in log:
        if master_pat.match(line):
            print(line.strip())
```

If I misread the logic and is not working, please comment.

Comment: @AlexHall Roger @ C Panda because I am comparing log files do you think its the size of Log file which is making it slow and also thank for introducing any, I implemented it in my code.

Comment: @PukhrajSingh NO. that is not a factor as long as you are using an iterator(`log`) , not a list(`log.splitlines()`) or a big string(`log.read()`). If the file is 100MB you are dealing with a line of text each time in memory. But thats python 3.x, DO CHECK OUT WHAT `open` RETURNS in python 2.x

Comment: Files are also lazy iterators in Python 2, that hasn't changed.